# InfiniteLoader and react-redux

Tags: react-redux, react-virtualized

Component InfiniteLoader from [react-virtualised](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) requires function passed as property loadMoreRows to have signature like `{ startIndex: number, stopIndex: number }): Promise`. 
I'm using redux in my project, so `loadMoreRows` is a redux action creator like this:

```
const fetchEntities(start, stop) {
  return fetch(`${myUrl}&start=${start}?stop=${stop}`)
}
const loadMoreRows = ({ startIndex, stopIndex }) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return function(dispatch) {
      return fetchEntities(startIndex, stopIndex).then(
        items => dispatch(simpleAction(items)),
        error => console.log(error)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

after that, this action is connected to react component containing InfiniteLoader using connect function from react-redux.

So I'm not sure, how can I satisfy signature requirement, as redux action creators don't return any value/

Comment: as I understood from source code of react-virtualised, it is not required to return Promise from loadMoreRows function. although, if you don't, it's your obligation to call child.forceUpdate() to update underlying components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**eyeinthebrick** is correct. A Promise is not a *required* return value.

When you "connect" a Redux action-creator, invoking it (dispatching it) actually returns a Promise. So for example I think you could do something more like this...

```
function fetchEntities (start, stop) {
  return fetch(`${myUrl}&start=${start}?stop=${stop}`)
}

const loadMoreRows = ({ startIndex, stopIndex }) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      const items = await fetchEntities(startIndex, stopIndex)
      await dispatch(simpleAction(items))
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

At which point `InfiniteLoader` can just await the returned Redux promise.

Comment: can't check right now, as I don't use es7 yet. my current solution is updating with hand by compassion of downloaded items in ComponentWillRecieveProps. so if there are new downloaded items, I call ```virtualScroll.recomputeRowHeights()``.

Comment: You don't need ES7. You can replace the async/await with normal Promise chaining and it should still work. :)

Comment: Brian, I think you're presuming the presence and use of some middleware, probably redux-thunk; out of the box, AFAICT dispatch just returns the action.